# how to display data in vf page like thatstandard salesforce detail page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

how to move that value into selected place properly? i want within one row label,value display?

[image]

Comment: You might also want to try adding mode="inlineEdit" or mode="maindetail" to the pageBlock.

Answer (score 0):

Putting an [apex:pageBlockSectionItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm) around each label/field pair will give you the conventional Salesforce layout e.g.:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Account Name"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!account.name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    ...
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```